# Eigenvectors of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector

Let $M$ be a square  matrix of order $n\times d$. Let $\xi_{1},\dots,\xi_{n\times d}$ be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ formed of eigenvectors of $M$. We have

$$\xi_{i}=(\lambda_1, 0, \dots, 0) + \cdots + (0, \dots,0,\lambda_n)$$

where $0, \lambda_j\in \mathbb{R}^{d}$.  We can write $\xi^{i}$ as
$$\xi_{i}=\alpha_{i,1}(\tilde{\lambda}_1,0,\,.\,.\,.\,,0)+\alpha_{i,2}(0,\tilde{\lambda}_2,0,\,.\,.\,.\,,0)+.\,.\,.\,+\sqrt{1-\alpha_{i,1}^2-\,.\,.\,.\,-\alpha_{i,n-1}^2}(0,\,.\,.\,.\,,0,\tilde{\lambda}_n).$$
We want to prove that there exist $\alpha_0>0$ small enough and $i_1,\,.\,.\,.\,,i_{(n-1)\times d}$ such that
$$\alpha_{i_k,l}>\alpha_0\qquad\text{for}\;k=1,\,.\,.\,.\,,(n-1)\times d\;\text{and}\; l=1,\,.\,.\,.\,n-1.$$

Comment: What is $\alpha_0$? As it’s currently written you can just choose any positive number smaller than the other $\alpha$s, as long as they are nonzero.

Comment: What is a square  $n \times d$ matrix? This means nothing to me.

Comment: @David Handelman - They mean an $nd \times nd$ matrix. They're using $\times$ to mean multiplication, not separation of matrix dimensions.

Comment: (To be fair, there was an explanation that the confusing terminology "square $n \times d$ matrix" meant $n \times d$ rows and $n \times d$ columns, but, for some reason, @vidyarthi edited it out.)

Comment: The $+$ signs mean $\oplus$, right? (Else the lengths of the vectors don't match.) Also, what does "small enough" mean in an existence statement?

Comment: @darijgrinberg - My understanding of the question is that the "zeros" are d-dimensional zero vectors (and the $\lambda$s are similarly d-dimensional), so the $+$ signs really are addition (of vectors living in $\mathbb{R}^{nd}$).